# Why is __setitem__ not invoked when changing list type data?

Tags: python-2.7

in the example below, there is a class with a `__setitem__`-method that works as it should, if data is set via `=`. However, if for instance data of type `list` is set implicitly using the `.append`-method, the `__setitem__`-method is not invoked. Is there some way to ensure that `__setitem__` (or something like "`__moditem__`") is invoked whenever the data is set or modified?

```
class MyClass(object):
    data = {}

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.data[key] = value
        print "I do not like change."

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.data[item]


c = MyClass()
c['list'] = ['hello']   #does invoke setitem
c['list'].append('world')   #does not invoke __setitem__
```

What is the appropriate way to deal with this problem? Of course one could replace the last line by

```
c['list'] = c['list'] + ['world']
```

but if this class is in a class library, the user might not know that. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__setitem__` is invoked by following syntax only:

```
obj[key] = value # this equals to obj.__setitem__(key, value)
```

In other cases, when you use `obj[key]` `__getitem__` is invoked.

For example:

```
class MyClass(object):
    data = {}

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.data[key] = value
        print "__setitem__ called"

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        print "__getitem__ called"
        return self.data[item]


c = MyClass()
c['list'] = ['hello']   # __setitem__ called
c['list'].append('world')   # __getitem__ called
```

In other words, in the last line when you use c['list'], firstly `__getitem__` is invoked and it returns pointer to initialized above list ['hello']. After that, `append` method of this pointed is called.

Answer (score 2):

`__setitem__` is invoked when mutating the container itself, not when mutating the contained elements. There's just no way for a container to monitor when items it happens to be holding happen to be changed. Consider this code, after all:

```
c = MyClass()
c['list'] = ['hello'] # Invokes setitem
foo = c['list'] # Grabs a reference to the object just put into the container
foo.append('world') # setitem is, of course, not invoked
```

If you find yourself wanting to do this, it's possible that you want the container to hold (or, at least, return), not standard list types and whatnot, but proxies which report back to a central datastore. The `xml.etree` module is a good example of this sort of thing.